# How to customize labels for axis tick marks according to user input (RShiny app)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggplotly

I'm making an interactive RShiny scatter plot in which the user can select what variables to display on the x and y axes. I want to make it such that depending on the variables that the user selects, the labels next to each tick mark along the x and y axes is either a % or $ sign.

When I run what I currently have, I end up with "Error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'". I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

```
scale_x_continuous(
      if (input$x_axis %in% c("total_spending_from_all_known_sources",
                              "total_spending_from_all_known_sources_per_child",
                              "total_state_and_tanf_spending",
                              "state_tanf_per_child_spending",
                              "three_year_olds",
                              "four_year_olds",
                              "total")){
        labels = scales::comma
      } else if (input$x_axis %in% c("three_year_olds_pct",
                                     "four_year_olds_pct",
                                     "x3s_4s_pct")){
        labels = scales::percent
      }
 )
```

Comment: Do `labels = if (…) scales::comma else … `.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is

```
label_format <- if (input$x_axis %in% c("total_spending_from_all_known_sources",
                                        "total_spending_from_all_known_sources_per_child",
                                        "total_state_and_tanf_spending",
                                        "state_tanf_per_child_spending",
                                        "three_year_olds",
                                        "four_year_olds",
                                        "total")){
  scales::comma
} else if (input$x_axis %in% c("three_year_olds_pct",
                               "four_year_olds_pct",
                               "x3s_4s_pct")){
  scales::percent
}

scale_x_continuous(labels = label_format)
```

*Note: In case the if failed both conditions then label_format will be NULL*